# What happens if we use/install 2.3 build in 2.2 device

Tags: android

I am working on application which should go into android 2.2(Froyo) and android 2.3(GingerBread) devices.

I have built application with android 2.3 SDK , and Installed the same application in 2.2(Froyo) and 2.3 (Ginger Bread) devices.

In both the devices application installed successfully and it is working properly.

I want to know if we install the higher version build into lower version devices is there any chances to face problems.

Till now I didn't found any issue with this.

I didn't used the MIN:SDK version field in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only users from version 2.2 and up to download your app, just make sure your minimum SDK version is 2.2 by putting this line in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

If you want an upper bound limit as well, you can add:

```
android:maxSdkVersion="10"
```

So users with Android SDK version 2.2 up to 2.3.3 will be able to install your app.

Regarding problems: If you're using a specific SDK API then just make sure to add an if clause around it to make sure you're on the right version. The best thing to do is change the target to 2.2 just to see if you have any compilation errors... Then you'd know what to change.
Then just fix the problems, change back to 2.3 and build.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the minimum sdk attribute in the manifest file users with 2.2 won't see your application on the market. It specifies that your application supports 2.2 so that users can see the app on the market.

Make sure any functionality that you use from 2.3 has an alternative functionality so that 2.2 users have the ability to actually use your application.

Answer (score 1):

yes , u can find problem ,

try to install that app on android 1.6

it's about API version , there will be some APIs in your app doesn't supported in  a lower API version